# Accessing an array from different classes in C++ (MFC)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

Being an old time VB6.0 programmer, I'm learning VC++ (MFC) with VisualStudio, with a small sample I've written as follows. I created a class that populates the **myAdapters** array as follows:

```cpp
    class CAdapter
    {
    public:
        int m_IPv4;
        string m_AdapterName;
        CAdapter* myAdapters;
        int adapterCount;
    
        CAdapter() {
            myAdapters = nullptr;
            adapterCount = 0;
        }
    
        ~CAdapter() {
            delete[] myAdapters;
        }
    
        void addAdapter(CAdapter adapter) {
            CAdapter* newArray = new CAdapter[adapterCount + 1];
    
            for (int i = 0; i < adapterCount; i++) {
                newArray[i] = myAdapters[i];
            }
    
            newArray[adapterCount] = adapter;
            adapterCount++;
    
            delete[] myAdapters;
            myAdapters = newArray;
        }
    
        CAdapter* getAdapters() {
            return myAdapters;
        }
    
        int getAdapterCount() const {
            return adapterCount;
        }
    
        void GetAdapters() {
            CAdapter adapter1;
            adapter1.m_IPv4 = 192168001;
            adapter1.m_AdapterName = "John";
            addAdapter(adapter1);
    
            CAdapter adapter2;
            adapter2.m_IPv4 = 192168002;
            adapter2.m_AdapterName = "Jane";
            addAdapter(adapter2);
    
            CAdapter* adapterArray = getAdapters();
    
            for (int i = 0; i < adapterCount; i++)
            {
                printf("Element %d in main: %d %s\n", i, adapterArray[i].m_IPv4, adapterArray[i].m_AdapterName);
            }
        }
    };
```

**However, I need to access the myAdapters element from *any* function or class, anytime. (that's whay I'm trying to do with the previous code, you can simply ignore the sample code below this point).** So I asked certain AI to alter the code to call the GetAdapters function from one class, and the ShowAdapters function from another class, which resulted in:

> To allow the **GetAdapters**() function to be called from one class and
> the **ShowAdapters**() function to be called from another class, you can
> make the **myAdapters** array and the **adapterCount** variable public members
> of the **CAdapter** class. This will allow other classes to access and
> modify these variables.
>
> Here's an example of how you can modify the **CAdapter** class to make the
> **myAdapters** array and **adapterCount** variable public members

```cpp
    class CAdapter {
    public:
        // constructor
        CAdapter() {}
    
        // public member variables
        CAdapterInfo* myAdapters;
        int adapterCount;
    
        // public member functions
        void GetAdapters() {
            // ...
        }
    
        void ShowAdapters() {
            // ...
        }
    };
```

> With this modification, you can now create an instance of the **CAdapter**
> class in one class, call its **GetAdapters**() function to populate the
> **myAdapters** array, and then pass the instance to another class that can
> call its **ShowAdapters**() function to display the contents of the
> **myAdapters** array. Here's an example of how you can do this:

```cpp
    class MyClass1 {
    public:
        void doSomething() {
            // create an instance of the CAdapter class
            CAdapter adapters;
    
            // call the GetAdapters() function to populate the myAdapters array
            adapters.GetAdapters();
    
            // pass the adapters instance to another class that can call its ShowAdapters() function
            MyClass2 class2;
            class2.showAdapters(adapters);
        }
    };
    
    class MyClass2 {
    public:
        void showAdapters(CAdapter& adapters) {
            // call the ShowAdapters() function to display the contents of the myAdapters array
            adapters.ShowAdapters();
        }
    };
```

Essentially, the proposed code is correct and it works. However, what Mr. GPT didn't understand is that I *cannot pass the adapters instance to MyClass2* whenever the showAdapters function is to be called from events such as the **OnCbnSelchangeCombo1** from a ComboBox element, because in such function I have no access to the **adapters** instance created by MyClass1.

I told that to the AI and it responded with this that dramatically altered the sample code:

> One way to avoid passing the adapters instance from **MyClass1** to call
> the **ShowAdapters** function from **MyClass2** is by making the **myAdapters**
> array a static member of the **CAdapter** class. This way, the **myAdapters**
> array can be accessed directly from any class that includes the
> CAdapter header file. Here's an example of how this can be done:

**CAdapter.h:**

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <string>

class CAdapter {
public:
    static void GetAdapters();
    static void ShowAdapters();

private:
    static int adapterCount;
    static CAdapter* myAdapters;
    
    std::string m_AdapterName;
    std::string m_IPv4;
};
```

**CAdapter.cpp:**

```cpp
#include "CAdapter.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "iphlpapi.lib")

int CAdapter::adapterCount = 0;
CAdapter* CAdapter::myAdapters = nullptr;

void CAdapter::GetAdapters() {
    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    DWORD dwRetVal = 0;

    // Make an initial call to GetAdaptersAddresses to get the size needed.
    GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_UNSPEC, GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_PREFIX, nullptr, nullptr, &dwSize);

    // Allocate memory from sizing information.
    myAdapters = new CAdapter[dwSize];

    // Get adapter information.
    PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES pAddresses = reinterpret_cast<PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES>(new BYTE[dwSize]);
    dwRetVal = GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_UNSPEC, GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_PREFIX, nullptr, pAddresses, &dwSize);
    if (dwRetVal == NO_ERROR) {
        // Iterate through all adapters and add them to the array.
        PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES pCurrAddresses = pAddresses;
        while (pCurrAddresses) {
            if (pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddressLength != 0) {
                // Add adapter to the array.
                myAdapters[adapterCount].m_AdapterName = pCurrAddresses->AdapterName;
                myAdapters[adapterCount].m_IPv4 = pCurrAddresses->IpAddressFirst->IpAddress.String;
                adapterCount++;
            }
            pCurrAddresses = pCurrAddresses->Next;
        }
    }

    delete[] reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(pAddresses);
}

void CAdapter::ShowAdapters() {
    for (int i = 0; i < adapterCount; i++) {
        printf("Adapter Name: %s\n", myAdapters[i].m_AdapterName.c_str());
        printf("IPv4 Address: %s\n", myAdapters[i].m_IPv4.c_str());
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

(*Side note:* For no reason at all, the AI rewrote the entire code to use the [GetAdaptersAddresses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersaddresses) API function. This was a (remarkable) deduction from the conversation, I never mentioned any API nor included them in the sample code. I'm using *GetAdaptersInfo*, which is almost the same, so the it was quite accurate.)

Since I'm new to C++, the proposed code introduces many breaking changes that would take a long time to adapt to my MFC application, and I'm not convinced that this is the best method or if it even works (all previous code did work with minor adjustments for MFC). Why there's no easy way to declare and access a "global" array in C++, like I used to with Visual Basic by simply declaring the array in the global scope, making it accessible to all forms, dialogs and modules? Is there an easier way to do this? **Essentially, I want the myAdapters array to be populated by a function from the CAdapters class, and then access that array from any class, function and dialog item from the MFC program somehow.** Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remember that AI knows less about C++ than you do. all it knows is how to string together tokens in a fashion that will convince a human that the AI is right. They flat-out suck at programming (unless they're copying an example from somewhere on the web, but that makes them a [cargo cult programmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming), and smurf knows we've got more than enough of those losers hanging around). Go back to your original code and ask questions about that. Or wait until folks teach AI how to actually use C++. I don't think that'll be too far down the road.

Comment: It seems relevant at this time to point out the current [ChatGPT ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned).

Comment: "Why there's no easy way to declare and access a "global" array in C++" - Accessing a global array in C++ is trivial. Just define the array in global scope and you can access if everywhere. That doing such a thing is a bad idea in general is a separate matter.

Comment: Unlike Visual Basic, globals won't be advertised to the entire program in C++.  You need to put a *declaration* in a header file and include it everywhere that needs to access it.

Comment: P.S. ordinarily I'd try to answer a question like this, but you've clouded it up with so much AI junk I can't really decipher what you're trying to do.

Comment: Consider simplifying your problem.

Comment: You need two pieces to work together to be able to use a variable with static storage duration: A declaration so that the compiler knows about the existence of that variable, and a definition to reserve a chunk of memory where the data lives. It's the declaration that commonly confuses folks. If were to you put `int i = 42;` in a file *globals.h* and included that into multiple translation units, you'd wind up with multiply defined symbols linker errors. Instead, put a declaration into *globals.h*: `extern int i;`, and a definition into *globals.cpp*: `int i = 42;`.

Comment: @Iinspectable thanks, that seems a good solution, would you mind expanding it in a reply so I can accept the answer? There is no globals.h file in the Single MFC Dialog app created by the Visual Studio assistant. Should I declare the array in globals.h and type extern to reference that array in the other .cpp files where I want to use it?

Comment: @MarkRansom, I said what I'm trying to do both in the second and the last paragraph, the text is now **bold** to make it even more clear. Sample code by AI helped me understand more of the C++ language, yet it does not apply to solve this particular case.

Comment: You never get a second chance to make a first impression.  Your question may be the model of purity now, but it doesn't matter - I'm not going to look at it again.  Your #1 priority on this site has to be making your question clear and concise if you want the best help.

Comment: @MarkRansom thanks, indeed the original question was too cluttered with info which could probably have been ommited, sorry about that. I hope someone provides a more complete answer with sample code because C++ handles things very differently than VB and the learning curve is quite steep.